# PDO. Подключение и работа с базой данных

Tags: php, pdo

В первый раз взялся за PHP, делал по гайдам на ютубе, но пришел в тупик. С подключением к базе данных проблем вроде нет, но получить результат SQL запроса так и не смог...

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host = $db_host;dbname = $db_name", $username, $password);
    $info=[];
    if ($query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM WORK")){
        $info = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
    } 
    else {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());}
```

В результате получаю ошибку: `Array ( [0] => 3D000 [1] => 1046 [2] => No database selected )`

Дополню: SQL запрос в phpMyAdmin выполняется корректно.

Comment: удостоверьтесь, что в `$db_name` нужное лежит. подключается оно к серверу, а не к базе, поэтому с подключением проблем может и не быть, а база не указана. И переменные в сроках лучше заворачивайте в скобки `{$var}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть большая вероятность, что дело в пробелах в строке

```
("mysql:host = $db_host;dbname = $db_name", $username, $password)
```

Там всё должно быть слитно (имеется в виду в первом аргументе)

Comment: тсс. по ролику с ютуба жеж

Comment: @teran там может IDE  с большим межсимвольным интервалом настроена %)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php в целом в документации нечего не сказано, о том, что должно быт слитно. Но подозреваю, раз потенциально имя БД может содержать пробелы, то удалять их из строки никто не будет. Но в таком случае, странно, что не выводит нечто про то что БД не найдена

Comment: @teran да, там не сказано, но, ЕМНИП, я с таким уже сталкивался.

Comment: да, дело было именно в пробелах... И на это я потратил пол дня(

Comment: @teran ↑↑↑  Воооот. Для меня это тоже было странно. Но тем не менее

Comment: @OlegMerkulov Думаю никто такого не ожидает, т.к. нигде не написано об этом.... но если брать из мануала, то лучше один-в-один))