# Ошибка подключения к базе данных php

Tags: php, сервер

Всем привет, нужна помощь. Вот код:

````
```
<?php
    $connect = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=db; charset=utf8_general_ci", '******', '********');
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO forum.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date')");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Форум</h2>
<div class="block">
<?
    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM forum.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){
            echo "<p>{$comment['data']}</p> {$comment['username']} :";
            echo "<br>";
            echo " {$comment['comment']}";
            echo "<br>";
?>
<div class="line"></div>
<?
        }
    }else{
        echo "Пока нет ни одного коментария :(";
    }
?>
</div>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="block-comment">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="10" rows="5" placeholder="Ваш комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
<style font-size=""></style>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Выскакивает ошибка:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set' in /var/www/******/data/www/******/index.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/******/data/www/********/index.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', '*****', '*******') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/*******/data/www/********/index.php on line 2.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [PDO. Подключение и работа с базой данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1422540/pdo-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: какая версия PHP, кстати ?

Comment: Я арендовал хостинг, и мне кажется дело не в версии php, потому что там есть встроенный IDE в панели управления.

Comment: Вообще, версия php 8.1.17

Comment: значит проблема скорее всего в пробелах, как в ответе выше

Comment: а если вместо utf8_general_ci поставить UTF8? тоже не оч?

Comment: Так у меня кодировка базы данных стоит general_ci

Comment: А пробелы я убрал

Comment: Всё, та ошибка которая в описании, исчезла. Появилась новая:Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /var/www/*****/data/www/*******/index.php on line 24

Comment: ищи её на стаке.......такой вопрос тысячу раз задавался

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1364103/191482

Comment: Cпасибо""""""""